# HttpSecurity permitAll and WebSecurity ignoring functions for un-Auth URL's?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

This question might seems like duplicate but none of the below answers explained when to use:

```
`http
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/h2-console/**", "/user/register/**").permitAll()`
```

and

```
`web
   .ignoring()
   .antMatchers("/h2-console/**", "/user/register/**")`
```

1. [HttpSecurity, WebSecurity and AuthenticationManagerBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998731/httpsecurity-websecurity-and-authenticationmanagerbuilder)
2. [Difference between Web ignoring and Http permitting in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652267/difference-between-web-ignoring-and-http-permitting-in-spring-security/55652599)

Going through StackOverflow asnwers and several articles I got to learn that:

**configure(HttpSecurity)** allows configuration of web based security at a resource level.

**configure(WebSecurity)** is used for configuration settings that impact global security. Using this a URL is completely ignored from Spring Security Filter Chain.

When i am using `permitAll()` it only works if i have disabled **csrf**: `http.csrf().disable()` because Spring Security filter chain is still active.

But with `web.ignoring()` URL are ignored completely.

Still a lot of articles uses `http.permitAll()` for `/login` or `/register` like [like this one](https://www.baeldung.com/security-none-filters-none-access-permitAll) and [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions)

So I want to understand,

**Why** should we even use `http.permitAll()` at all for Un-Auth URLS like `/login` and `/register`?

**Why** can't we use `web.ignoring()` for `/login` and `/register`?

**Why** `web.ignoring()` is commonly used for serving static content like `css` and `webjars` etc only but not with `/login` and `/register`?

Comment: When you `permitAll` you basically say regardless of anything I want everyone to be able to access this URL, however all the other security features (secure headers, csrf protection etc) are still applied. With `ignoring` all those features are also ignored and open your application for possible vulnerabilities.

Comment: thanks for the response. I want to understand the vulnerabilities. I mean if i want a `URL` to be unauthenticated then what security vulnerabilities can still be there? This will help me to understand and decide which `URLS` should be `web.ignored()` and which should be `http.permitAll()` in future scenarios.

Comment: Cross Site Scripting, XSS attacks, content-sniffing to name a few. Spring Security has features to protect against those (and to enable them in the browser by sending additional headers). Spring Security does more then "just" authentication and authorization. Ignoring them also means there is no security context being set etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `@M. Deinum` pointed out, I am concluding the answer and I have updated the documentation for the same in [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/8825/files).

**`configure(WebSecurity web)`**

> Endpoint used in this method ignores the spring security filters,
> headers, CSRF etc. see HeadersConfigurer, CsrfConfigurer. Instead, if
> you want to protect public endpoints against common vulnerabilities,
> then see `configure(HttpSecurity)` and
> `HttpSecurity#authorizeRequests` configuration method.

**`configure(HttpSecurity http)`**

> Public endpoints that require defense against common vulnerabilities
> can be specified here. see `HttpSecurity#authorizeRequests` and the
> `permitAll()` authorization rule for more details.